# SQL and calling a function

Tags: python, function, sqlite

wondering if anyone can help.
Im am using Python ,AppJar, SQL together.
And after i call a function from appjar called login.go() which makes a GUI start.
Later in the code i need a function to run but it never does, it is called as well but for it to work it needs to be after login.go() if i put it before or call it before it means the GUI never happens and after it never runs instead. Ive tried to solve for ages and no clue, ANY help is appreciated massively. this is some of the code.

```
 #////RUNNING CODE\\\\#
'''THE FIRST PART OF CODE TO RUN'''
login.go()

def GetNews (usr):
   conn = sqlite3.connect("uHubDatabase3.db")
   cursor = conn.cursor() #connects to database

   CollectUserNews=("SELECT NewsOpt1 FROM UserTable WHERE Username = ?") #sets 
   the finding of the username from the database as a varaible 
   cursor.execute(CollectUserNews,[(usr)])

    NewsRemoveSTR = str(cursor.fetchall())
    print(NewsRemoveSTR)
    removechars = "'(),[]" #Avoids the error of special characters caused by the database outputting strings (Text)
    for char in removechars:
        NewsRemoveSTR = NewsRemoveSTR.replace(char,'')

    NewsLink1=("SELECT Link FROM NewsTable WHERE Name = ?")
    cursor.execute(NewsLink1,[(NewsRemoveSTR)])

    d = feedparser.parse(NewsLink1)
    d['channel']['title']
    print (d.feed.title)#Checks it was found durig testing

    #Artcile 0 ----------------------------------------------------
    home.addLabel("subtitle", (d['entries'][0]['title'] ),1,1)
    home.setLabelBg("subtitle", "black")
    home.setLabelFg("subtitle", "white")

    home.addMessage("para", (d['entries'][0]['description'] ),2,1)
    home.setMessageBg("para", "lightgrey")
    home.setMessageFg("para", "black")

    #Artcile 1 ----------------------------------------------------
    home.addLabel("subtitle1", (d['entries'][1]['title'] ),1,0)
    home.setLabelBg("subtitle1", "black")
    home.setLabelFg("subtitle1", "white")

    home.addMessage("para1", (d['entries'][1]['description'] ),2,0)
    home.setMessageBg("para1", "lightgrey")
    home.setMessageFg("para1", "black")
    return (NewsRemoveSTR)
GetNews(usr)
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/, and generally unclear what you expect and what you get.

Comment: @Murphy sorry for late response, my issue is the function never runs if it’s after the login.go() which is a function but if it before the login.go() never runs. Very odd. When the function runs it’s collecting a web url to make an RSS feed which is added to he GUi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No code after `login.go()` will be executed until the GUI is closed - calling `login.go()` starts the GUI's event loop, this is where tktiner is checking for events.

I would define the function at the top of your code, and then put the line that calls `GetNews(usr)` on the line before `login.go()`

If the `GetNews(usr)` function call takes a long time to complete (which it could, if the DB has a lot of table, lack of indexes, etc) then there might be quite a delay before the GUI shows up.

If the `GetNews(usr)` function call never returns, then the GUI will never show.

You *could*, put the call to `GetNews(usr)` into a thread, so that the GUI can start, and the function runs in the background.

Have a look here for more info: http://appjar.info/pythonThreads/

It would look something like: `login.thread(GetNews, usr)`

**NB.** updating the GUI from a thread is risky. You would be safer putting all of the GUI updates into thread safe calls, e.g. `login.queueFunction(home.updateLabel, "l1", "new label text")`

Comment: Thank you I will look into this in the morning but this should help a lot.